# Eclipse crash with mistake:unhandled event loop exception out of range CashCode

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, event-handling

while i was writing my code that error occured and there was a window with that error(i am not sure if it was written out of range, i think it was something like this). Now as i open eclipse there is a premature end of file. In the Error Log there's written "Copy did not complete normally and "Could not load repository template extension contributed by org.jboss.tools.common.mylyn with connectorKind jira".  Please see the log for more information." I am workin with Jboss, i hope this information helps you. Thanks to everybody.

This is the rest:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.tools.common.xml.XMLUtilities.getDocument(XMLUtilities.java:252)
    at org.jboss.tools.common.xml.XMLUtilities.getElement(XMLUtilities.java:244)
    at org.jboss.tools.common.xml.XMLUtilities.getElement(XMLUtilities.java:197)
    at org.jboss.tools.jst.web.kb.internal.KbProject.loadValidationContext(KbProject.java:352)
    at org.jboss.tools.jst.web.kb.internal.KbProject.resolveStorage(KbProject.java:286)
    at org.jboss.tools.jst.web.kb.internal.KbBuilder.build(KbBuilder.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new eclipse install? Or have you possibly removed any atlassian plugins?

You might look at this reference at jboss.org:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-10338?_sscc=t